# Changing Contents of Select Based on Choice from another select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, react-tsx

Im having a hard time rendering subgenres based off the parent genre.  Ive included a codeSandbox originally forked from the mui_grouped_select CSB at the bottom.

As you can see in the CSB I tried a few different approached to try to get subGenre and ended up passing an empty array just so the page would load.

Feel free to convert to a ".js" if that's easier.

I can see that I can get the right code in the first handle hook but after that I am struggling withupdating the subGenre to have the selectedGenre.sub array.

P.S. new to JS and TSX. I come from a C99/Python background mostly if that helps any.

https://codesandbox.io/s/genre-subgenre-v1mfr3?file=/demo.jsx

Comment: What is `subL`? Seems like an empty array that never got populated.

Comment: Im sorry that I am just now seeing this. I am editing the post with a sandbox.